# How to test the Cordova app for iPhone without a Mac

Tags: ios, visual-studio, cordova

I use Cordova with Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10.
Is there a way to test the app directly from Visual Studio to my iPhone (registered as developer) without a Mac?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You can't test it with visual studio, but you can upload your code to phonegap build service or any other online build service and they will build the app for you

Answer (score 2):

if your app is HTML5 only(e.g. Cordova ), you can try Intel XDK with app preview on your mobile device. No OS X is required for this.

You can refer to the introduction in the following
https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/intel-xdk-app-preview-overview

But seriously, it's not bad to invest some money on an Mac Mini for your cross platform apps anyway.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately you can't deploy or test your app on the iPhone/iPad/iPod without a Mac. To compile your app for Apple Platforms you need Xcode. Xcode only runs on Mac.

However you can try and run Mac OS X in virtual machine, but it's violating Apple's terms of service.

Comment: Ah ok, but they proposed remote IOS build agent. How this work?

Comment: @suifer I think that you code on Windows and compile on another Mac machine remotely. Either way you need a Mac. There is NO way you can build for iOS without a Mac or not in Xcode. And there never will be. If you want to develop for iOS or OS X - buy a Mac, cheapest is Mac Mini, $499.